# Yarn/NPM linked package is not showing changes in browser

Tags: reactjs, caching, npm, webpack, yarnpkg

**Context**

I have two projects, `main` and `styles`.
`Main` uses `styles` as an npm package, importing it as `@companyname/styles`. 
I need to make changes to `styles` and want to link it locally to see these changes in `main`.

This is a react app, using Webpack and babel. Yarn is the favoured package manager.

**Problem**

Using `npm link` OR `yarn link` works in so far as I can go into the `node_modules/@companyname/styles` folder in `main` and see my changes in there.

However, no changes are reflected in the browser.

I only use one or the other (yarn/npm) at a time, but problem exists with either one

**Things I've tried**

- Deleting `node_modules`, reinstalling and re-linking
- Unlinking and re-linking
- Rebuilding
- Clearing npm cache, clearing yarn cache
- Viewing site in incognito
- Deleting `dist` folder in `main` and reinstalling
- Adding `CleanWebpackPlugin` to my webpack config
- Adding `hot: true,` to my `devServer` config in webpack config.

**TL;DR**

Yarn/npm link not showing my changes in browser, however will show changes in `node_modules`. Something causing browser to not read changes. Please help.

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this? Having the same problem.

Comment: Same here. Did you find the cause?

Comment: I'm having this problem too. Anyone...? Help...?

Comment: Just to be sure (although if you're seeing the changes in `node_modules` you have probably done it), here are the steps I follow to link my local library: in `styles` (at the level of `styles/package.json`), I run `yarn link`. Make sure that in `styles/package.json`, name is `@companyname/styles`. Then in the consuming package, `yarn link @companyname/styles`. Then I restart the development server, and it works. Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried deleting the lock file?

```
rm package-lock.json
npm clean-install
```

Answer (score 0):

the cause is in webpack configuration. It took me days to find the perfect combination for symlink packages.

In my case, my project was a Vue app.

So here's a summary of my findings for people from the future (for Webpack 5):

```js
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  resolve: {
     symlinks: false // Important so that symlink packages are resolved to their symlinked location
     // If your package contains frontend framework components, prevent two instances of the framework (React for example), one from the app and the other one from the symlink package
     // Kudos to https://stackoverflow.com/a/68497876/11840890
     alias: {
        react: path.resolve('./node_modules/react'),
        '@': path.resolve(__dirname, './src') // Add this alias if you get a new issue after setting up the first one
     }
  },
  snapshot: {
    // Even though added changes on the symlink package may trigger rebuild, they might not be seen on the browser (using HMR or not)
    // To prevent reloading dev server every time, add this (it will include only node_modules but your package in the cache):
    managedPaths: [
      /^(.+?[\\/]node_modules[\\/](?!(@author[\\/]your-package))(@.+?[\\/])?.+?)[\\/]/,
    ],
  },
}
```