# Solve having more than one copy of React in the same app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, webpack, package.json

I'm developing a React module locally. For that, I'm linking my module using `npm link`.
The module is imported successfully but hooks are failing inside the module. It's throwing the following error:

> Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a
> function component. This could happen for one of the following
> reasons: 1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the
> renderer (such as React DOM) 2. You might be breaking the Rules of
> Hooks 3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
> See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to
> debug and fix this problem.

Checking the suggestions at [React docs](https://es.reactjs.org/warnings/invalid-hook-call-warning.html), I can confirm my app is using duplicate versions of React since the following code returns false:

```js
// node_modules/mymodule/src/index.js
export { default as ReactFromModule } from 'react'
```

```js
// src/index.js
import React from 'react'
import { ReactFromModule } from 'mymodule'
console.log(React === ReactFromModule) //false
```

[This issue](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/13991) is full of suggestions but they are confusing. How can I solve it?

Note: Im not breaking rules of hooks, the error appears only when importing the module from an application.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Duplicate ReactJS import issue when using npm link to test component before publishing as npm package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57871715/duplicate-reactjs-import-issue-when-using-npm-link-to-test-component-before-publ)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

**In the module** you are developing, add the conflicting packages to `peerDependencies` (and remove them from `dependencies` or `devDependencies`):

```json
  // package.json
  "peerDependencies": {
    "react": "16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "16.13.1"
  },
```

Execute `npm install` in your module.

Now add `react` and `react-dom` to the webpack configuration of **your module** as `externals`. These packages shouldnt be included in the bundle of the module (the app that uses the module will provide them):

```js
// webpack.config.js
module.exports = {
    /*
    rest of config...
    */
    output: {
        filename: "index.js",
        pathinfo: false,
        libraryTarget: 'umd', // In my case, I use libraryTarget as 'umd'. Not sure if relevant
    },
    externals: {
        // Use external version of React
        "react": {
            "commonjs": "react",
            "commonjs2": "react",
            "amd": "react",
            "root": "React"
        },
        "react-dom": {
            "commonjs": "react-dom",
            "commonjs2": "react-dom",
            "amd": "react-dom",
            "root": "ReactDOM"
        }
    },
};
```

Then, after building your module, **in your application** you can check that both versions are now the same:

```js
// node_modules/mymodule/src/index.js
export { default as ReactFromModule } from 'react'
```

```js
// src/index.js
import React from 'react'
import { ReactFromModule } from 'mymodule'
console.log(React === ReactFromModule) // true :)
```

Comment: `externals: { react: 'react' }` — works for me

Comment: Specifying the externals the very same way saved my life :D

Answer (score 20):

Adding `react` and `react-dom` as `peerDependencies` in the `package.json` didn't work for me.

I had to add an alias to the webpack configuration file:

```
// webpack.config.js
resolve: {
  alias: {
    react: path.resolve('./node_modules/react'),
}
```

Comment: highly underrated answer, THANK YOU!

Comment: smart approach!

Comment: I owe you a beer

Answer (score 6):

In response to another comment, merely moving React to peerDependencies does not adequately resolve the issue in all cases. I would reply to that comment directly, but StackOverflow requires more reputation to respond to wrong answers than it does to post them.

I have a shared React component module built using Webpack and have run into the same issue. I've outlined one possible fix in this comment below which requires modifying peerDependencies and using npm link in a fashion similar to the answer shared by mtkopone.
https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/13991#issuecomment-841509933

My solution is a bit hacky and I wouldn't recommend it for long-term use. If you are using Webpack (which you tagged this question as), this article may detail a more permanent solution (https://medium.com/codex/duplicate-copy-of-react-errors-when-using-npm-link-e5011de0995d). I haven't tried it yet, but the author seems to have tried all the (incorrect) solutions out there and is also running into the hooks issue while trying to build shared component libraries.

The author of that article is trying to debug a Create-React-App app. While CRA uses webpack under the hood, you can't access the webpack.config directly, so the author has to perform some workarounds to do so. If you aren't using CRA, but just plain Webpack, then you could consider using the resolve.alias section of webpack.config to ensure there are no duplicate copies of React (see: https://blog.maximeheckel.com/posts/duplicate-dependencies-npm-link/)

Comment: Link-only answers are generally [frowned upon](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/204922) on Stack Overflow. In time it is possible for links to atrophy and become unavailable, meaning that your answer is useless to users in the future. It would be best if you could provide the general details of your answer in your actual post, citing your link as a reference.

Comment: I don't understand how my answer was "link-only", unless the four paragraphs of text I wrote appear as whitespace in your browser.

Comment: Your four paragraphs of text only refer to things mentioned in the articles/sources you linked. It is impossible to implement your suggestion without visiting the sites. So when those links break, your answer becomes useless.

Answer (score -1):

I was attempting to use the `peerDependencies` and removal of the `devDependencies` and it was failing.

It turned out I had a `node_modules` folder in one of the parent folders of the library I was working on and the duplicate version of React was being loaded from there instead of the tool that was trying to use the React library.

Rather than editing the `devDependencies` to remove react I just wrote a small script to delete anything that's in the `peerDependencies` from the `node_modules` folder.

```
npm view --json=true . peerDependencies | jq -r 'keys | .[] |  @text' | while read dep; do  rm -r ./node_modules/${dep} && echo Removed ${dep}; done
```

Answer (score -2):

In my case I was also missing `import React from 'react'` from couple of files.
[check this](https://github.com/rollup/rollup/issues/3130#issuecomment-534472923)