# listitem onclick material ui giving an error

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, material-ui

Hi I am trying to write navigation list like below.

Codepen Link: https://9huof.csb.app/
https://codesandbox.io/s/nervous-water-9huof?file=/src/index.js

```
 const NavList = () => {
 const history = useHistory();
 return (
   <div>
    <ListItem button onClick={() => history.push("/reports")}>
     <ListItemIcon>
       <DashboardIcon />
     </ListItemIcon>
     <ListItemText primary='Reports' />
   </ListItem>
   <ListItem button onClick={() => history.push("/quiz")}>
     <ListItemIcon>
       <PeopleIcon />
     </ListItemIcon>
     <ListItemText primary='Quiz' />
   </ListItem>
  </div>
 );
};
```

Where ListItem called inside List from the functional component like below.

```
 <Drawer variant='permanent' open={open}>
      <Toolbar
        sx={{
          display: "flex",
          alignItems: "center",
          justifyContent: "flex-end",
          px: [1],
        }}
      >
        <IconButton onClick={toggleDrawer}>
          <ChevronLeftIcon />
        </IconButton>
      </Toolbar>
      <Divider />
      <List>
        <NavList />
      </List>
    </Drawer>
```

When I click on quiz it says "Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:"

Comment: check this answer it might be due to more than one copy of React in the same app 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66488492/solve-having-more-than-one-copy-of-react-in-the-same-app

Comment: you could post https://codesandbox.io/ link of reproducible code

Comment: "react": "^17.0.2",
 "react-dom": "^17.0.2" I am using this @shubhamjha

Comment: Tried removing node_modules and installing again. Still the same

Comment: can you share reproducible code on https://codesandbox.io/?

Comment: https://9huof.csb.app/ Please check

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/nervous-water-9huof?file=/src/index.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the `render` props of your `Route` components. Use an inline function as seen [here](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Route/render-func). So you need to change your `Route`s from this:

```
<AuthRoute path="/quiz" render={Quiz} />
```

to this:

```
<AuthRoute path="/quiz" render={() => <Quiz />} />
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of render in your route change the prop to component like so

```
<AuthRoute path="/quiz" component={Quiz} />
```