Using React + Vite: Invalid Hooks, Duplicate Instances of React
I'm working on a simple React + Vite site. As soon as I began implementing React Hooks, I got an Invalid Hook error that led me to finding I have multiple versions of React.
Screenshot of Multiple React Versions in Terminal
Now I know what the issue is, but I'm not sure how to fix it/go about removing a duplicate React version. Any suggestions? It looks like there is only one version listed in my dependencies:
Dependencies Screenshot

There is no issue. That is perfectly normal. npm has even marked one of them as deduped showing that there is only one copy of the dependency installed and shared.

see if this helps
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66488492/solve-having-more-than-one-copy-of-react-in-the-same-app
